# Equivalent of collect_set(spark sql function) in flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-sql

I was using Spark until now, and switching to flink now. In spark there is a function collect_set which is used to collect unique values for a column from multiple rows(This is a text field for error_code and was grouping by on other columns like org)
Example:

```
org_id | error_code
  A.   | 200
  A.   | 204
  B.   | 404
```

After passing thru collect_set it becomes:

```
org_id | error_code
  A.   | 200, 204
  B.   | 404
```

Now I want to do the same thing in flink table, convert it to datastream and store in my db
Now flink has something call COLLECT, It returns a multiset like following

```
org_id | error_code
  A.   | {200=1, 204=1}
  B.   | {404=1}
```

There is a distinct keyword in collect but it results in error when converting to datastream
Is there a predefined function which can help do it similar to as I used to do in Spark

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if flink has this method but you can use a rich function such as process() and keep the error_codes in a value state.